# C Using malloc on a char string

Tags: c, malloc

This simplified version of the program has the task of storing a char string in an array. If the product with the given name is already occupied, I don't store it, otherwise I use malloc to allocate space for the chain.
But I'm getting a segmentation fault and I can't find the fault
Complet program https://onecompiler.com/c/3yqnk3e5s

```
struct product{
  int *regal;
  char *name;
}product;

struct product allocList(struct product **list, int *alloc)
{
  *list = (struct product*) malloc(sizeof(struct product)*(*alloc));
  (*list)->regal = calloc(100, sizeof(int));
}

int isInList(struct product **list, int *listSize, char *item, int *itemIndex)
{
  for(int i=0; i< *listSize; i++)
    if(! strcmp(item, list[i]->name))
    {
      (*itemIndex) = i;
      return 1;
    }  

  return 0;
}

int insert(struct product **list, int *alloc, int *listSize, char *item, int regalIndex)
{
  int itemIndex = 0; 

  if(isInList(*(&list), *(&listSize), item, &itemIndex))
    return 0;

  list[(*listSize)]->name = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char)*(strlen(item)+1));
  strcpy(list[(*listSize)]->name, item);

  (*listSize)++;
  return 1;
}

int main()
{

  struct product *list = NULL; int listAlloc = 2000; int listSize = 0; allocList(&list, &listAlloc); 
  
  char *str = "abcd"; char *str1 = "bcd";
  insert(&list, &listAlloc, &listSize, str, 1);
  insert(&list, &listAlloc, &listSize, str, 1);
  insert(&list, &listAlloc, &listSize, str1, 1);

 
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: The `allocList()` function doesn't initialize `name`.  The structure keeps no records of how big either the `regal` or `name` elements are — how much space is allocated.  I suspect that the uninitialized `name` is a serious problem.  The lack of size information merely makes it hard to work reliably with the structure.

Comment: Not clear to me where the list is actually set to anything other than NULL. it's not in `insert` and `isInList` uses the list without a NULL check.

Comment: The code in your post is not the same as the code at the online compiler you link to. The difference is critical to your question. I see issues in the code here, but not the potential segfault that I see in your linked code.

Comment: allocList() is declared to return a product but doesn't return anything.  It segfaults on the line "list[(*listSize)]->name = malloc(sizeof(char)*(strlen(item)+1))".  Probably out of bounds write to `list[1]`.

Comment: @AllanWind Good catch. I overlooked that one with the mishandling of indirections/dereferencing on that line.

Comment: I recommend avoiding pointers to pointers in this application. Prefer functions that accept *and return if necessary* `struct list*`. Also don't pass indices and other small data by reference if the function doesn't change them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your program segfaults in `insert()` on the first line and when you fix that the following line:

```
   list[(*listSize)]->name = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char)*(strlen(item)+1));
   strcpy(list[(*listSize)]->name, item);
```

As list is of type `struct product **list` it means you deference whatever data is stored `sizeof(list) * (*listSize)` elements after `list` which is undefined behavior when `*listList > 0`.  Instead you want to dereference list, then access a array element *listSize.  I suggest you use `strdup()` instead of `malloc()` + `strcpy()`:

```
    (*list)[*listSize].name = strdup(item);
```

The next step would be to introduce a struct to hold your list implementation details, and pass that around instead of the double pointers.

Comment: Why pointer arithmetic? `(*list)[*list_size]`.

Comment: To me `(*list)[*list_size].name` is less readable than `(*list + *listSize)->name`.  It also adds another change from op's code (going from `->` to `.`).  I wrote both options up initially.  Happy to add it back if you think it improves the answer.

Comment: "less readable" I don't think so. An array is an array. Use square brackets to index an array.

Comment: @n.m. I changed it to match your preference.

Comment: Also it is not correct to say that "you treat it as if it was a struct product *list". I would have said "list is a pointer to an array of struct, but you treat is as an array of pointers to struct". (This is not formally correct to the T because it is a pointer-to-the-first-element-of-an-array rather than just an array, but it gets the point across).

Comment: @n.m. Rewrote the relevant section.  Better?